# how to load the SQL tables data into ignite cache in table format?

Tags: java, ignite

Loading sql table data into ignite cache but its getting loaded in key value pairs but i would need to load in table format, can you please advise?
Sample code snippet:

**IgniteCache<Integer, BinaryObject> binaryCache = ignite.createCache(cacheName).withKeepBinary();
BinaryObjectBuilder builder = ignite.binary().builder(cacheName);
builder.setField(columnsName, sourceResultSet.getString(values)); } binaryCache.put(resultSetRowCount, builder.build()); }**

Comment: please Improve question details --->
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As a general point, you appear to be asking the same question again and again, with only slight variations. You might benefit from a little more background reading so you can make your questions more focused.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite is a key-value database with SQL support. It's entirely valid to load data into a table using the key-value API and query it using SQL.

You need to define the table structure when you create your cache. Since you don't to use model classes/annotations, you'll need to [use query entities](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api#query-entities).

Example from the documentation:

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    private float salary;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
    CacheConfiguration<Long, Person> personCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<Long, Person>();
    personCacheCfg.setName("Person");

    QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity(Long.class, Person.class)
            .addQueryField("id", Long.class.getName(), null).addQueryField("age", Integer.class.getName(), null)
            .addQueryField("salary", Float.class.getName(), null)
            .addQueryField("name", String.class.getName(), null);

    queryEntity.setIndexes(Arrays.asList(new QueryIndex("id"), new QueryIndex("salary", false)));

    personCacheCfg.setQueryEntities(Arrays.asList(queryEntity));

    IgniteCache<Long, Person> cache = ignite.createCache(personCacheCfg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, in my case tables selection is dynamic, can you please advise how to handle dynamic tables and fields in CacheConfiguration and QueryEntity ?

Comment: As noted previously, Ignite is not a document database.